# Control printout of floating point decimals, in Pandas DataFrame with decimal.Decimal entries?

Tags: python, pandas, decimal, precision

Consider this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal

my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "c"])
my_df = my_df.append({'a': 1, 'b': 3.0/7, 'c': Decimal(3.0/7)}, ignore_index=True)
print(my_df)

print("-------")

with pd.option_context('float_format', '{:.4f}'.format, 'display.expand_frame_repr', False):
  print(my_df)
```

This prints out:

```
   a         b                                                  c
0  1  0.428571  0.42857142857142854763807804374664556235074996...
-------
   a      b                                                  c
0  1 0.4286  0.42857142857142854763807804374664556235074996...
```

Being aware that one can control the printout of number of decimals in a float in Pandas DataFrame with `pd.option_context('float_format',...`, I have tried to apply the same approach to an element, which is of `decimal.Decimal` class. As the test code printout shows:

- the float printout has been truncated from `0.428571` to `0.4286`, as expected
- however, the Decimal object is still printed with a ton of decimals

I'd like to keep the Decimal objects in my Pandas DataFrame, however at certain points, I'd like to print them with a smaller, limited number of decimals - like what  `with pd.option_context('float_format',...` does for floats.

Is this controlled "truncated/rounded printout" of Decimal in a Pandas DataFrame possible - and if so, how can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe one way you can do this is by changing [the context](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.getcontext) associated with the decimal object and recalculating the column with decimals.

Note that this seems to only work if the Decimal is calculated like `Decimal(3.0) / Decimal(7)`. But if your decimal is complicated I think you can get around this by doing `Decimal(x/y)/Decimal(1)` for every decimal object in the column instead of considering each of the denominators one-by-one.

My modified code looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
from decimal import *


my_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["a", "b", "c"])
my_df = my_df.append({'a': 1, 'b': 3.0/7, 'c': Decimal(3.0)/Decimal(7)}, ignore_index=True)
print(my_df)

print("-------")



#We change the precision and then reinitialize the ['c'] column with the same decimal objects.
getcontext().prec = 4
my_df['c'] = [Decimal(3.0)/Decimal(7)]

with pd.option_context('float_format', '{:.4f}'.format, 'display.expand_frame_repr', False):
  
  print(my_df)
```

Output:

```
   a         b                               c
0  1  0.428571  0.4285714285714285714285714286
-------
   a      b       c
0  1 0.4286  0.4286
```